# C# trying to send queries

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net-core

I got a linux server with mariadb installed and i want to send queries to that server with C# with this script

```
namespace SQLTEST
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            CreateCommand(
                "INSERT INTO TEST(name) VALUES ('sample');",
                "server=IPadress;database=test;uid=root;password=**;pooling=false;"            );
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
        private static void CreateCommand(string queryString, string connectionString)
        {
            try{
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                    command.Connection.Open();
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Connectin  open");
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change the connection string multiple times. It seems like i cant get over the command.connection.open line
This is the error i keep getting

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Error says it all - check that connection string is correct and pointing to an existing server

Comment: Do you know any Connectionstring templates. It seems like i need a different "template" but i tried them all. The properties a correct

Comment: Dude - you're not going to have much luck connecting to a MariDB database instance with the Sql Server library!  You need a MySql/MariaDB library!.  Q: Are you developing your project (the C#/.Net Core client) on Windows, with MSVS, or "something else"?  If you're using MSVS: 1) Open your project, 2) Use NuGet to install the MariaDB library, 3) Modify your connection string, 4) Try again.  Look here for details: https://mysqlconnector.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have MariaDB (essentially MySQL) as your database and you are trying to use Microsoft SQLServer client libraries to access it. It'll never work - they are completely different databases.

Use [MySQL library](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) instead